# What jquery/css method(s) and properties are involved in connecting page scrolling to animations?

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation, scroll

Sorry if the title is not worded very well. Lately I have seen a few pages where, when you scroll up or down, rather than simply scrolling the page, the scroll position remains fixed, and the scrolling action animates certain elements on the page. The homepage of magnani has lots and lots of this

http://www.magnani.com

is there a property you modify to do this? seems like you would have to stop a page from scrolling, then hook into the scroll action to make it do something else. is this correct at all? Just not sure where to start with this one. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the "Parallax" effect? Actually the pages is still scrolling but the backgrounds are fixed.

Comment: something else is happening though because, such as the paper plaines throughout, these things are not just scrolling against a fixed background, they are (seemingly) moving across the page.

Comment: Yep there is more to them, but the main idea is Parallax. Google it, check the answer below, check this: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ you see that there are a lot of examples and demos in the net. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this plugin: http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

You may be able to find something in the source code that could help you out